# What's the relationship between Connectors and Streams in ksqldb?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

So I'm reading the documentation about Connectors [1] and I try to figure out what the relationship between streams and a sink connector [2] is.

The source connector [3] has a property named "table.whitelist" which to my understanding tells Debezium to only copy those tables over to ksqldb. My interpretation here is also that CDC is used to also sync changes occuring on those source tables with ksqldb, but that is not mentioned.

However, what about the relationship between individual streams and sink connectors? There is no such property like "stream.whitelist". Does that really mean that all streams will be sent to all connectors?

For example I want to only send data from stream str1 to connector con1, and only send stream str2 to con2. Is that possible?

[1] https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/concepts/connectors/#natively-supported-connectors

[2] https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#sink-config-options

[2] https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/source-connector/source_config_options.html#jdbc-source-configs

Comment: Sink connectors read from topics AFAIK. There is a sink connector property that lists the topics a connector should read from.

Comment: I find this quite weird if this is the case. To me a source is where data comes from, a sink is where it goes to. They really miss to better describe fundamental concepts.

Comment: Tbf I think it's more accurate to say that sink connectors read from topics, but topics can be created by streams and (ksqldb) tables.  So the route is something like datasource -> source connector -> topic -> ksqldb -> topic -> sink connector -> some data sink

Answer (score 0):

> tells Debezium

The linked documentation is for the JDBC Connector, not Debezium. There is no CDC used.

---

There isn't really any direct relations; ksqlDB can simply embed Kafka Connect worker process, or send requests to a remote Connect cluster.  Doesn't matter if the source/sink is a database, or some other system, other than the "natively supported" JDBC connector.

You'd `CREATE STREAM/TABLE` from **topics** generated by source connectors, and create sink connectors from the output **topics** of other `STREAM` definitions, not configure connectors to ksqlDB streams.